# send email from php not working

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code below. However, I'm unable to send emails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sonic Train</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300italic,400" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

                <!-- The main CSS file -->

</head>





                                <body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
   <div class="col-sm-12" style="background:url('titleimage.jpg');color:white;"><center><font size="20">Sonic Train</font></center>
<!--<div class="col-sm-12" style="background:url('image1.jpg');color:white; height: 500px;">-->
<center>Train machine learning models at sonic speed...</center></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="jumbotron" style=" background-color:skyblue;">
<a href='testemail.php?hello=true'>Send an update</a>
<?php
  function runMyFunction() {
    echo 'I just ran a php function';

$to      = 'myemailud@us.edu';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: myemailud@us.edu' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: myemailud@us.edu' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }

  if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    runMyFunction();
  }
?>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no error ?

check your mailserver

Comment: Which part of your code is using PHPMailer?

Comment: @BenM, hmm didn't get that. I'm calling the mail(..) function inside runMyFunction which is called on button click.

Comment: @WRDev, sorry check mailserver? I did check my inbox. Don't see any mail.

Comment: @PepperBoy PHPMailer is a specific class which is written using PHP: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. From the code you've posted here, it doesn't look like you're using it.

Comment: do you see "I just ran a php function" printed on screen to make sure your runMyFunction get called. check your webserver and see if you see any mails pending in mail queue.

Comment: whats your file name ?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal, sorry, file name?

Comment: @JitendraSanghani, I see the echo message printed, checked my mail box, but don't see any mail.

Comment: is it .html or .php format is your php code running properly??

Comment: The file is testemail.php

Comment: tey removing 'X-Mailer: PHP form header. One more option is to add mime 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n", this may fix the issue but not sure. What is the webserver OS?

Comment: @JitendraSanghani, sorry, I couldn't get the change. Can you please reply as an answer with the code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
function runMyFunction() {
    echo 'I just ran a php function';

    $to      = 'myemailud@us.edu';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';

    $headers  = "Return-Path: myemailud@us.edu\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: myemailud@us.edu\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
```

the above code is working properly on my website. Are you testing on your development environment or the hosted server. In case of development machine i highly doubt if you have SMTP mail server configured. Linux machines have default smtp module.

Please provide more details of your test server and can help you with few commands to verify the mail server settings.

You are checking email in your inbox which is a mail client and everyone is asking you to check mail server.